# complexity of calling a function with a for loop

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Im quite new to computational complexity, but i know that a nested for loop will give O(n^2). in my case i have a for loop that calls a function which has a for loop within it. will the complexity be O(n) or worse?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if(i != 0){
             System.out.println();



                printt(i);

      }
      }
}

public static void printt(int i){

    for(int j = 0; j <= 10; j++ ){
        if(j !=0 ){
        System.out.print(j*i+" ");
    }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the number of print statements(the second one itc) that are executed if you run this snippet of code.

The easiest way to reason about this is to go ahead and run the program, and you will notice that you have **81** values being printed out, which tells you that you have 9 calls to the nested function for each run of the outer loop (9 time again). So it ends up being *O(n^2)*.